# Parallel instances to run an external serial software

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess, popen

I am attempting to write a python function that uses multiprocessing to execute multiple instances of a external serial software. Using the code below I am able to "start" all of the runs of the external software, but it appears that only 1 instance of the software is actually computing (i.e., log files were generated for every run but only one instance is updating the log). One issue with the external program that I am using is that it only accepts one specific input file name. My original solution to this is to start the Processes 1 by 1 while waiting 10 seconds in between, so that I can update the information of this input file after each process instance has started. In otherwords, I write a new input file each instance starts.

Overall, what I would like to do is allocate X # of CPUs (via a scheduler) to my python program and then have my python program start X # of serial instances of the external software, so that all instances run in parallel. I should also not return to the main python program until all instances of the external software have completed. I appreciate any helpful insights! I am relatively new to this type of parallelism, so I apologize if my question has an exceptionally simple solution that I don't see.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE
import time

def run_parallel_serial(n_loops=None, name=None, setting=None):

    processes = []
    for i in range(1, n_loops+1, 1):
        prepare_software_input(n_loop=i, info=name)
        processes.append(Process(target=run_software))
    count = 0
    for p in processes:
        update_input(settings[count])
        p.start()
        time.sleep(10)
        count += 1

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print("Done running in parallel!")
    return
```

The uprepare_software_input and update_input functions are used to write and overwrite the input file used by the external software. The run_software function uses the subprocess module as the following

```
def run_software():

    p = Popen([PROGRAM_EXEC, SOFTWARE_INPUT_FILE], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
    del(p)
    return
```

p.s. I am not married to multiprocessing. If there is an alternative strategy with a different module, I am happy to switch.

Comment: You say it *appears* that only one process is updating the logs - do you have any other way to verify that each unique file content is being processed? Popen has a *cwd* parameter: instead of overwriting the input file for each process, could you put input files (with the required name) in different folders/directories then specify a different directory for each process using the *cwd* argument ?

Comment: I tried to put the inputs in different directories and run with the cwd arg of popen and the result is still the same. It appears that the jobs are still hanging.